# Trying to split my code into multiple pages in React, Javascript. Receiving multiple errors

Tags: javascript, debugging, react-native

I am trying to split my React project into multiple sections. I first split ListItem.js out and it worked with no problem. I am now getting errors when trying to split my Button.js and my Input.js out. Button.js is giving me an error of duplicate declaration. Input.js ran the app without errors, but disappeared from the app.

This is the main page, App.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, ImageBackground, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import ListItem from "/Users/Westin/assignment5/ListItem";
import Input from "/Users/Westin/assignment5/Input";
import Button from "/Users/Westin/assignment5/Button";


export default class App extends React.Component {
  state ={
    thing: "",
    things: [],
  };

  thingValueChanged = value =>{
    //alert(value);
    this.setState({
      thing: value
    });
  }

  onClickingAdd = () =>
  {
    if(this.state.thing === "")
    {
      return;
    }

    this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          things: prevState.things.concat(prevState.thing)
        };

    });
  }



  render() {
    const thingsOut = this.state.things.map((thing,i) => (<ListItem key = {i} thing={thing} />))
    
    
    return (
      <View style={styles.background}>
      <ImageBackground source={require("/Users/Westin/assignment5/background.jpg")} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
       <Text style={styles.headerText}>My Favourite Things</Text>
      </View>
      </View>

      <View>
        {InputOut}
      

      
      <View>
        {ButtonOut}
        </View>
        </View>    
      
    
      <ScrollView>
        {thingsOut}
        </ScrollView>
      </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    opacity: 0.7,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flexstart',
    paddingTop: 30,
    color: 'white'
  },
  background: {
    flex:1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    
  },
  header: {
    padding: 10,
    
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 35,
    color: 'white',
  }
});
```

This is my ListItem.js page that runs fine:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';

const ListItem =(props) =>
(

    <View style={styles.listItem}>
        <Text style={styles.listtext}>
            {props.thing}
            </Text>
        </View>


);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    listItem: {
        width: "100%",
        padding: 10, 
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        opacity: '0.7',
    },
    listtext: {
        color: 'white',
    }

  });


  export default ListItem;
```

This is the Button.js page that is running as a duplicate declaration error:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';

const Button =(props) =>
(

    <View style={styles.addButton}>
   <Button
      title="Add"
      onPress = {Props.this.onClickingAdd}
      />
        </View>


);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        addButton: {
        width: "30%",
        }
  });


  export default Button;
```

This is the Input.js page that has disappeared from the app:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';

const Input =(props) =>
(

    <View style={styles.input}>
      <TextInput 
      value={Props.this.state.thing}
      placeholder="Add your favourite things" 
      style={styles.inputbox}
      onChangeText={Props.this.thingValueChanged}
      />
      </View>


);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
input: {
  flexDirection: "row",
  width: '100%',
  justifyContent: "space-evenly",
  alignItems: "center",
  backgroundColor: "black",
  opacity: '0.7',
},
inputbox: {
  borderWidth: 2,
  height: 40,
  width: "70%",
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  padding: 10,
}});


  export default Input;
```

Comment: You're importing Button and then declaring a const Button. That's the conflict.

Comment: Also, you have multiple `Props.this...` references. What are these referencing? Have you tried `props.thing` instead of `Props.this.state.thing`?

Answer (score 0):

1. In `App.js`, you didn't use the `Input` component rather there's `InputOut` component which is nowhere written in the provided code. Also, you have provided `{Props.this.state.thing}` `value` in the text field, which should be `Props.thing`.
2. Duplicate declaration error

   You have used `Button` before declaring the `Button` componenet in following code:

   import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, >>>>Button<<<<, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';

   Just change the name of `Button` form one of the two places, then it should work fine.